# How can shift my tab view from one to another in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, tabview, fxmlloader

I am doing a JavaFx project . I have a table view which is populated by few names (e.g. BG Manager , User Management , Find Acl , ....) . Each time I click on each one of those names (or each row of that table ) it will open a new tab which is again populated with the information I set out earlier inside . Here is an example function that being called once I click on a row with the name of BG Management :

```
private void callBGManager(){
    try {
        Tab tab = new Tab ();
        FXMLLoader bgm = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/BGMWindow.fxml"));
        BGMController  bgmc = new BGMController(_session);
        bgm.setController(bgmc);
        Parent root = bgm.load();
        for (Tab tabs : TabPane1.getTabs()){
            if (tabs.getText().equals(ListView1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())){
                SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = TabPane1.getSelectionModel();
                selectionModel.select(tab);
                return;
            }
        }
        tab.setContent(root);
        tab.setText(ListView1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        tab.closableProperty().set(true);
        TabPane1.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane1.getTabClosingPolicy().SELECTED_TAB);
        TabPane1.getTabs().add(tab);
        SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = TabPane1.getSelectionModel();
        selectionModel.select(tab);



    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

There is no problem in the compilation or operation of this code as it works well . Here is the scenario for the better understanding of the situation . I have lets say 5 rows in my list and every time I click on each if it's not already opened it will show up and if it's already open nothing happens . Lets say I am already in another tab view and the BG Manager is already open . How can I shift to BG Manager once I click re-click on it :)

Comment: Surely you just want `selectionModel.select(tabs)` instead of `selectionModel.select(tab)` in the `for` loop? (It would make it clearer if you move `Tab tab = new Tab()` to after the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Danial u can use `(row)cell.setUserData();` and by deafult set for each true value. And onClick on this row(cell) you should to check this data `(row)cell.getUserData();` and if it is true than change it to false and open window in another case do nothing.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
table.setRowFactory( tv -> {
  TableRow<MyType> row = new TableRow<>();
  row.setOnMouseClicked(event ->{
        boolean result = (boolean) row.getUserData();
        if(result){
            row.setUserData(false);
            //There will be your method to open new window
            methodToOpenNewWindow(row);
        }else{
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setContentText("This entity already was opened.");
            alert.show();
        }
    });
  return row ;
});
```

In method `methodToOpenNewWindow` on close window set row `userData`  back to true .